# Problems with Abyss X1 Web Server

Tags: webserver, localhost

I believe I've set my server up properly, but whenever I access http://localhost, instead of seeing the index.html page I see a page that just says, "It works!". I've tried tracing the file back to some place on my computer, but I can't find it there. I've reinstalled the server software 3 or 4 times. I can access the homepage at http://localhost:8000, but shouldn't it also appear at http://localhost?

Comment: By default http uses port 80 not port 8000.

Comment: @DavidPostill both 8000 and 80 take me to the same page